# how to find a row in mvc list and use that for jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have the following list in mvc:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiscProductName)
            </td>
            <td class="lblAmount">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td class="lblCount">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
            </td>
            <td class="entAmount">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.EnteredAmount)
            </td>
            <td class="entCount">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.EnteredCount)
            </td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
    }
```

where the first 3 columns(productname,amount,count) are for display and the next 2 columns are of input type.

Now my requirement is,when an input is entered in EnteredAmount" and "EnteredAmount" and in change or blur event of "EnteredAmount" i need to check the values with "Amount"and "Count" respectively and display an image beside last column based on input.

For Ex:
Amount : 50
Count: 2
EnteredAmount :20
EnteredCount : 3
Now we have to display some error image as the values(EnteredAmount and EnteredCount) doesnt match with Amount and Count respectively.

If it matches then some correct symbol.

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: in your blur och change event:

$(this).parent().find(".lblAmount")....

etc.

Comment: can I have a jsfiddle example.i have to compare decimal value with entered value(may be or may not be a decimal).Ex:if Amount is 50.00 and entered amount is 50

Comment: Can you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xayn93vs/5/

```
var precision = 0.00005,
    areEqual = function (a, b) {
        return Math.abs(parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b)) < precision;
    },
    checkEquality = function () {
      var $tr = $(this.parentElement.parentElement),
          sameAmount = areEqual($('.lblAmount', $tr).text(), $('.entAmount input', $tr).val()),
          sameCount = areEqual($('.lblCount', $tr).text(), $('.entCount input', $tr).val());

        $('td:last-of-type', $tr).
            removeClass('match nomatch').
            addClass(sameAmount && sameCount? 'match': 'nomatch');                                                                   
    };

$(".entAmount input, .entCount input").change(checkEquality).keyup(checkEquality);
```

You can see from my fiddle, that the ✔ and ✘ marks are added via CSS, using pseudo elements.

Comment: This does not validate decimals. Please take a look at OP's comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4t987qw/3/)

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".entAmount > input").keyup(function(){
    var myText = $(this).val();                     
    var toCheckText = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td.lblAmount').text());
    var otherVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("td.entCount").find("input").val();
    var otherText =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td.lblCount').text());  
      if(parseInt(myText).toFixed(0) === parseInt(toCheckText).toFixed(0) && parseInt(otherVal).toFixed(0) === parseInt(otherText).toFixed(0)) {
          //show image
          console.log("Matched!!");
      } else {
          //show error
          console.log("Not Matched!!");
      }

  });

  $(".entCount > input").keyup(function(){
    var myText = $(this).val();                     
    var toCheckText = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td.lblCount').text());
    var otherVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("td.entAmount").find("input").val();
    var otherText =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('td.lblAmount').text()); 
      if(parseInt(myText).toFixed(0) === parseInt(toCheckText).toFixed(0) && parseInt(otherVal).toFixed(0) === parseInt(otherText).toFixed(0)) {
          //show image
          console.log("Matched!!");
      } else {
          //show error
          console.log("Not Matched!!");
      }

  });
});
```

Comment: No need to create two almost identical functions. You can use a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple fiddle. Ugly but it shows what you need. Used closest instead of parent. Value parsing you should be able to do yourself with this example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".entAmount").change(function(){
    var myText = $(this).closest('tr').find(".lblAmount").text();                     
    if(myText = $(this))
      console.log("It matches!");
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4t987qw/)